# facebook requests 2.0 - using the data param

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to generate some apprequests using the js api + razor mvc in c#. I so far have the following:

```
FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Campsite request',
            data: 'cid=@Model.Stuff.Id.Replace('/', '-')&un=@Model.OtherStuff.Id.Replace('/', '-')'
        });
```

as you can see i'm trying to pass in the ids of stuff and otherstuff so that when the user follows the notification in their facebook page - i can grab these and do some processing from within my canvas app.

Thing is - they don't seem to be in the url or post?

How am i to do this?

I am using the c# facebook sdk also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be "hiding"/encapsulated inside the request itself. Check the request structure at the end of the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

Also I've written a tutorial about handling the requests and best uses of the `data` parameter [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-handle-application-requests-using-the-facebook-graph-api/45/). It's written in PHP but the approach should be clear enough to follow.

Comment: the c# sdk has a canvas auth part to it i hadn't worked out what it was for... up to now :)